# Gdal add coordinate point over geotiff

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I want to add some points that represent coordinates (in shapefile) onto geotiff image which is earth basically. I used command line:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 200 -ts 1000 600 -ot byte -l point point.shp land.tiff
```

but this just gave me a black backgrounded image with red dots. I'm new with gdal and gis so maybe my way could be a little bit wrong. Maybe ı should use gdal_grid but ı don't know how